# Is "Additionals" a word?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

Google Translate recognizes it as a noun, but search with it and Google suggests me to use `additional` instead.

Is it a recognized word? As in

> My order came with a list of additionals that were not considered for this transaction.

Comment: Recognised by who?

Comment: If it's a noun, and used to refer to distinct things, then it can be pluralized (with very few exceptions).  The use is unusual mainly because using "additional" as a noun is unusual.  (It's basically short for "additional thing".)

Comment: What's an additional? Do you mean an addition?

Comment: *In context*, it's easy to see what OP's cited usage of ***additionals*** is supposed to mean. But so far as I'm aware, all native speakers in all Anglophone countries would use *[optional] **extras*** here.

Comment: I wish I did agree with FumbleFingers but sadly, I'm quite sure many native speakers I've met in Australia and Zimbabwe, Colorado and California and every part of my own UK would happily use "a list of additionals" let alone think nothing wrong on hearing or reading it.

I'm equally sad to be equally uncertain even most, and I'm very sure nothing like all natives would use "extras".

Answer (score 1):

> OED **additional**
> **B.** n.
>
> **A thing which is added to something else; an addition, an extra.**
>
> 1639   T. Fuller Hist. Holy Warre ii. iv. 48   *Their second master
> made some additionalls to their profession.*

and then reasonably regularly used until

> 2006   K. Fletcher Partnerships in Social Care ii. iii. 38   *A
> typical group of perhaps 25 senior representative staff costs,
> conservatively, £3000 per meeting by the time additionals have been
> added.*

The word, as a countable noun, in this sense is not uncommon.

Comment: Good research. There's your answer: it's either outdated, business jargon, or both.

Comment: Everything awful is business jargon.

Answer (score -3):

It’s not really correct to say ‘additionals’ as a noun.

The correct usage would be ‘additional items’ or ‘additional requirements’ or ‘additional people’ or whatever the thing is.

‘Additionals’ or ‘the additionals’, would be a kind of slang abbreviation of ‘additional items’.

For example, Joe is in the warehouse and calls to his friend ‘Harry! Did you put the Additionals on the cart?’ Meaning, the additional *items*. But it’s not really proper English.

Unless it’s the name of a rock band.

https://m.facebook.com/The-Additionals-405174182888904/

Comment: OED has *additional* as a noun, attested from 1626 and still current.

Comment: Not in the online version. I did wonder if it might exist as a mathematical term, referring to ‘the numbers to be added’. https://public.oed.com/search/Additionals/?post_type=any

Comment: I don't know how Oxford decide what gets from www.oed.com to public.oed.com. [Here's the entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcMPg.png).

Comment: Still, it doesn’t fall well on my ears. It sounds to me like business or work slang, (or an Americanism) but not like normal English speech.

Comment: Fascinating list of old language though! ☺️

Comment: I said 'additionalS' not additional, @AndrewLeach do you suppose you can then say 'the additionals'? it doesn't really sound right, to me...

Comment: Did you look at the the OED entry? It may sound like jargon, but the word has been around for 400 years. Apart from demonyms like *Germans* there are other examples of adjectives becoming nouns and pluralisable (like the term [*ungulate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ungulate), perhaps) but those are quite rare, which is why this might sound odd. But what I think is immaterial: I took issue with your initial assertion and provided corroboration for doing so.